# Reverse the frequency count in python

Tags: python, string, count, frequency-analysis, word-frequency

Say, I have a data containing an item in line[1] followed by its frequency count in line[2]

```
Item     Frequency.Count
A            5
B            4
C            3
D            2
E            1
```

But I want the output to be like:

```
Data
A
A
A
A
A
.
.
.
C
C
C
D
D
E
```

This is somewhat the reverse of the following code:

```
my_list = sorted(word_freq.items(), key = lambda x:x[1], reverse = True)
for word,freq in my_list:
print ("%‐10s %d" % (word, freq))
```

You might think this is a silly approach to a frequency analysis but I wanted to learn if there are reverse operation for counting frequencies, does anyone have an idea about unsorting the given data given there are two columns? Thanks so much for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Input list:  **l = [['A', 5], ['B', 3], ['C', 1]]**

```
 out_put=[]
 [(out_put.extend([j for j in lst[0]*lst[1])] )) for  lst in l]
```

out_put : **['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C']**

Answer (score 0):

IF you loop around your item and in second loop just replicate it no of times the frequency list than you are done i guess.Please try this approach

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do that ? I think this is what @Navin Dalal meant (not sure though).

with

```
> l
[['A', 5],
 ['B', 3],
 ['C', 1]]
```

you can get what you want:

```
> list("".join([i*j for i, j in l]))
['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C']
```

The key part being:

```
[i*j for i, j in l]
['AAAAA', 'BBB', 'C']
```

Because you can multiply a string a number of times given by an integer.

Hope this helps.